# Multifunction textbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

I'm developing an online php application with a friend, which is the programmer as I'm a newbie in programing :), and I need a solution for the below problem.

A drop down textbox with preset-ed values from admin, with input and record values from users, with search&autocomplete feature.

Eg.: 
The preset values of the Admin are: Red, Green, Blue.
If the user types "G" the textbox goes for an autocomplete/search functions and indicate him what values can choose. Also the user can click the drop down menu and select himself the value.
BUT now, if the user wants a new value, as Yellow, he has to write it, and the script should memorize the value into the database (user's database, not admin's) with Enter or a button, and next time he log's on, the value will be available in the autocomplete/search function or by scrolling. 
Also would be grate if the script can sort ascending values by name :).

Many anticipated thanks and blesses for your help !

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: We searched here [link] (http://www.jqueryrain.com/2012/03/35-best-ajax-jquery-autocomplete-tutorial-plugin-with-examples) for scrips to do this but we could not find. Maybe you can recommend one that we can work on it.